# How can I access the ngrx store in the console?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I know it's a bit of no-no but in my browsers console, how can I access the ngrx redux store? The redux tooling obviously does it but I just want to be able to examine it via the console. Is it a global? If so, what is it's name? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using Redux Dev Tools for Chome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Comment: I do and love them. I have something specific I'm trying to investigate in the console though. Specifically, I want to write some js to do some filtering and examine some of the things in the state

Comment: You would just need to subscribe to the value(s) you're wanting to log unless I'm just not understanding your question.

Comment: I need to know how to access the store in the console. It’s as simple as that, access them all the other ways isn’t going to help me at the moment. I’m asking about the console specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (and hope) that it will not work without explicit exposure in the application.

You can make a function globally available that reads the current state and shows it in the console. Like this:

```
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [...],
    bootstrap: [...],
  })
  export class AppModule {
    public constructor(private store: Store<unknown>) {
      this.exposeStoreToGlobal();
    }

    public exposeStoreToGlobal() {
      if (!environment.production) {
        globalThis.showStoreSnapshot = () => {
          this.store.pipe(first()).subscribe((snapshot) => console.log(snapshot));
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you just have to call it in the console whenever you want to:

[image]